# Eager vs graph mode with Keras and TF2.0

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.x

I'm compiling a previously trained model in the graph mode:

```
inference_model = model_from_json(json.dumps(inference_model_dict))
inference_model.set_weights(original_model.get_weights())
inference_model.compile('adam', 'binary_crossentropy', run_eagerly=False)
```

When using it for prediction:

```
predictions = inference_model.predict(gen)
```

getting the following error:

ValueError: Calling `Model.predict` in graph mode is not supported when the `Model` instance was constructed with eager mode enabled. Please construct your `Model` instance in graph mode or call `Model.predict` with eager mode enabled.

I was trying to disable the TF2.0 default by

```
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```

- this didn't help neither.

Reading thru the Keras documentation, don't find how to follow this recommendation: "call `Model.predict` with eager mode enabled"

Originally, this model was trained in the eager mode. Does this matter? Can't this be overwritten somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by re-arranging the session related code.

Comment: I have the same problem. What do you mean by "re-arranging the session related code?". Did you run the code within a Graph and a Session in TF 2?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I had some issue with the way the sessions were defined (inherited from the TF1.15 code). Once simplified this, the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I have emploied the `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()` which solved my problem